# How to make a line/path appear in react-native-svg?

Tags: css, react-native, animation, svg

I am trying to get a given Line (or Path) object made in `react-native-svg` to appear.

Normally one would use `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to hack an effect. I applied those as a style to the Line/Path but it didn't seem to be applied.

How can I animate a set of lines/paths with css in react-native-svg? Ideally without having to manually animate each of them myself.

Comment: React Native Svg basically same with svg, but you should be using camel case prop names (not style, props), instead of dashes, eg: strokeDasharray https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#common-props

Comment: Ohhh I didn't try that! Also css animations work there?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can use react-native-reanimated (v2 is easy to learn) to animate svg props

Comment: Cool but that would mean individually tracking their prop value. Is there anything to start and forget? Like: "Draw Line from x1,y1 to x2,y2 with appear effect" and be able to generate a bunch easily? (I'm asking because with normal CSS that's possible and very easy)

Comment: Its not that easy with react native reanimated.. You can look at this example: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/useAnimatedProps/#example It uses path but its pretty much same

Comment: I've created a snack for you to test it: https://snack.expo.io/@truetiem/reanimated-svg-animation (You need to run it on a mobile device, web doesn't work)

Comment: Thank you, that's really cool of you! :)